# How can I add dataGrid's ObservablCollection of rows to ObservablCollection of DataGrid's and reset dataGrid upon creating new Tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, tabs

I have two views MainView in which I add Tabs.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MVM mvm = new MVM();

    private void AddInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = string.Format("Tab");
            mvm.Items.Add(new VM(s));
        this.DataContext = mvm;
    }
}
```

And TabView in which dataGrid is located.

```
 public partial class TabView : UserControl
{
    MVM2 mvm = new MVM2();
    public TabView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mvm.Invoice_Items.Add(new VM2());
        dataGrid1.DataContext = mvm;
    }
}
```

I have two ObservableCollections. One for Tab Items

```
class MVM : BVM
    {
        private ObservableCollection<VM> items = new ObservableCollection<VM>();

    public ObservableCollection<VM> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```

Another one for dataGrid's rows.

```
class MVM2:BVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<VM2> invoice_items = new ObservableCollection<VM2>();

    public ObservableCollection<VM2> Invoice_Items
    {
        get
        {
            return invoice_items;
        }
        set
        {
            invoice_items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Invoice_Items");
        }
    }
}
```

When I add new Tab my dataGrid's data is saved in all other Tabs, but I want to reset data in dataGrid in each new Tab and save it in third ObservableCollection that stores dataGrid's.

I suppose third ObservableCollection should be located inside ObservableCollection that stores Tab Items. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not sure, but what is wrong is you've INPC'd the OC's property.  Don't bother with that.  `public ObservableCollection<Something> Property {get;private set;}` is fine, if not preferable.